# Java NullPointerException when using Evaluation.areaUnderROC from Weka

Tags: java, weka

So I'm trying to evaluate the performance of a classifier on a test instance and when I try to get the area under the ROC, the following error is thrown:

> Java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at weka.classifiers.evaluation.ThresholdCurve.getROCArea(ThresholdCurve.java:268)
>       at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.areaUnderROC(Evaluation.java:382)
>       at Classifier_Search.runAda(Classifier_Search.java:74)
>       at Classifier_Search.acrossTest(Classifier_Search.java:142)
>       at Classifier_Search.main(Classifier_Search.java:511)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)

The code that is throwing the error is this:

```
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
String[] options = {"-P 100", "-S 1", "-I " + it, "-W weka.classifiers.trees.DecisionStump"};
AdaBoostM1 cls = new AdaBoostM1(); 
cls.setOptions(options);
cls.buildClassifier(train);
eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);
int index = test.classIndex();
return eval.areaUnderROC(index);
```

When I look up the javadoc for Evaluation ([javadoc for Evaluation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html)), It says that areaUnderROC needs to be set by an evaluateClassifier method. No such method exists.  Other similar methods (such as falsePositive) work just fine.  Has anyone encountered this problem? I can't find anything on OldNabble (Weka's help site).

Thanks!

EDIT: to clarify, test and train are both Instances objects that were created with the following code:

```
private static Instances readFile(File filename) throws IOException
{
CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
loader.setSource(filename);
Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
return data;
}
```

They are read from .csv files. Typically if there is something wrong with test or train, the error is thrown here.

Comment: what's `test` how is that being defined?

Comment: Yea the line number is important here, and I also think <code>test</code> might be the culprit.

Comment: @twain249: test is an Instances object and it's passed in from another method. I have used it to get other evaluation criteria

Comment: @m0skit0: It's the last line that I pasted

Comment: What is `test` set to before calling `eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);`?

Comment: @m0skit0: I have edited the post to include the code that generates test.

Comment: I don't think your code is the cause of the `Exception`. It's thrown in `ThresholdCurve.getROCArea()`. It looks like that method is called in `eval.areaUnderROC(index)`. Since [the documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/) says that if it can't find what you're looking for it returns a value instead of throwing an exception I think there might be something wrong with Weka. I never used it though. Just a guess.

Comment: I don't think so. I think he's just initializing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once again, I have the answer to my own question.  If someone disagrees with this answer, please let me know. The weka documentation for areaUnderROC, which already has one typo (it references a method, evaluateClassifier, which does not exist), has led me in the wrong direction. I think there is another error  in the form of a misleading explanation. areaUnderROC works (without throwing the exception) for two values: 0 and 1.  So, rather than taking the class index (the index of the attribute I am using as the class in the Instances object), what it actually wants is which class (of the two classes) to consider as positive.  Given the variable names in the documentation, I think it's reasonable to not understand this at first glance. I also think that since its explanation is in parallel with that of methods that *do* take the class index (rather than 0 or 1), it is also misleading.

Comment: I just stumbled across the same error. It really is the index of the class value, not the index of the class attribute.

Comment: What does the index of the class value mean?